# Having trouble using Maven resources within my IntelliJ projects

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm having a problem with resources that I add to my Java project with Maven and I'm not quite sure what the issue is.

I'm using IntelliJ. But have also tried using Eclipse with the same issue.

When I add a resource to my POM file and it downloads. I add it to my project but I am unable to fully use it.

For example, the WebDriverManager resource for Selenium. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/3.7.1 it has a method for setting it up that is `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();`.

However, I can only type in `WebDriverManager` with the rest of the command not being recognised and highlighted in red.

The same is occurring with Selenium itself when I add it via the POM file. I am unable to use the library fully with most commands going unrecognised.

Is this possibly a permission issue?

Comment: you said `I add it to my project`. How? Have you synchronized your project with maven? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html

Comment: I believe I have done that yes. The resource was added via the pom.xml file, I can see the resource has been added to my external libraries and I am referencing the file. However, when I try to reference its methods, IntelliJ only recognises part of what I am trying to do.

Comment: A shot in the dark: try invalidating the IntelliJ cache. Does build from the command line pass?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. This may sound obvious but I was previously trying to use methods outside of the main method.

Once I put the code in the main method. Things worked.

Doh.